# Capture screen shot on Android phone when playing video and camera preview

Tags: android, overlay, screenshot

I have two HTC phones, one is HTC desire and another is HTC aria. I'm using ddms to capture the screenshot on HTC desire before, it works fine. However recently I buy one HTC aria, and I found when doing screenshot on camera preview and video playing (e.g. youtube clips), the result goes black.

I think that might be some overlay issue, but just can't figure out how do capture screenshots on camera preview.

Comment: I have the same problem, and trying to figure it out. I'm on HTC Desire HD =(

Comment: I just got an HTC aria (yes i know it's 2017) and I'm having trouble taking a screenshot, do I need to root or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, this is probably just not possible.  Prior to Android 3.0, the DDMS screenshot facility was done by taking a copy of the framebuffer.  For surfaces in an overlay (often the case with video playback), this doesn't exist in the framebuffer so can't be included in the screenshot.