# Android Capture Screenshot during video play

Tags: android, capture

I Don't know here is the right place but How can I capture screen while playing video in an android device especially android 2.3.1.

When I Capture screen, just see play pause buttons and a black screen instead of video content.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241464/capture-screen-shot-on-android-phone-when-playing-video-and-camera-preview) thread, it doesn't seems to be possible (I had the same problem).

The only solution I found was to play the video on a Galaxy tab 10.1 and to use the screenshot function of the tablet, but it require to have a Galaxy tab 10.1 :/

Jokahero

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved if you play your video on surface texture. To play video on that surface texture would be needing bitmap(which will run in thread). you can then capture the bitmap on touch event for surface texture and convert it to jpeg in your desired folder.